# Page numbering doesen't work

Tags: page-numbering

I use sharelatex and I tried a lot of page numbering code, but none of them show me the number of the page.

My code begins with this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}


\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{10cm}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\textdegree}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sp}{Sp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ud}{d}
\DeclareMathOperator{\divv}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ctg}{ctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tgh}{th}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sh}{sh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cth}{cth}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcctg}{arcctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arsh}{arsh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arch}{arch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arth}{arth}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcth}{arcth}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\end{document}
```

And doesen't appear to me the number on the bottom of the page or elsewhere. 
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Sorry, it was a wrong title.

Comment: You're creating a non-existent document. What happens when you place some characters on the page... anything.

Comment: I don't understand. Everywhere I see this code for page numbering, but for me, it doesen't work.

Comment: (La)TeX creates the page numbering as part of the output routine. And this output routine is only executed if there's something on the page. Since you haven't provided _anything_, nothing is created. Period.

Comment: ...what happens when you insert `\mbox{}` between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as well? Do you see the page numbers then?

Comment: It was just an example, of course when I write something in the document it doesen't work also...

Comment: edit your example so that it shows the problem, as it is the expected result is no output so it is hard to comment

Comment: When I take your code and paste it into a project/file on ShareLaTeX I can't compile it (even with text in the main document). Errors due to conflicting `amsmath` and `mathastext` and "Undefined control sequence `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`...

Comment: Thank you! But I would need to them. :(

Comment: As it stands, I can't reproduce your problem since the document won't compile.

Comment: If you write some text in the first page it will compile, but the number won't appear.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Are you compiling with XeLaTeX?

Comment: I use sharelatex.

Comment: ShareLaTeX allows you to select the compiler. See [this image of what I'm looking at](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lP3Ux.png). Correct your current setup before anything else can be done... or at least provide some more detail.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but If I remove it, still doesen't work, and if I complie my code not with xelatex, there isn't any problem my code, but the number doesen't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. You're creating a non-existent document.

   (La)TeX inserts page numbers during page shipout. And, page shipout only occurs when there's content to be shipped out. Since that's not happening, no page numbers may be visible.
2. [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and [`mathastext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) doesn't always work together well.
3. The code doesn't compile with

   ```
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\textdegree}
   ```

   so I've removed it.
4. While you're using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set the document layout, you're adjusting it with other manual techniques:

   ```
   \addtolength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
   \addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
   \addtolength{\voffset}{-2cm}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{10cm}
   ```

   Of these, the last line *adds* 10cm to the *existing* `\textheight`. And since you're using an A4 paper size with "default margins", there's not enough room for the text block to fit on the page, despite pushing the content up by 2cm (`\voffset`).

After all the errors are fixed, removing

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{10cm}
```

allows you to see the page numbers.

For future reference,

1. when using `geometry`, use it (and only it) to adjust your layout;
2. Add the `showframe` option to see the actual layout. There's also the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) which does the same. It'll help you make sense of layout problems.

Comment: The problem is that when I remove this, \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\textdegree} I can't write ő letter.

Comment: Use `\H{o}`.....